# Python Dataframe: calculation and displaying in column sum of values based on specific IDs in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have following dataframe:

```
data = {'Project_ID': ['Project 1',  'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1'], 
     'participant_id': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1005, 1104, 1104, 1104, 1104], 
     'day':['Day_1', 'Day_2', 'Day_3', 'Day_1', 'Day_1', 'Day_2', 'Day_3', 'Day_4'], 
     'no_completed_tests': [5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5]}
```

I am trying to add column ‘completed_tests_(per_participant)’ which adds and displays 'no_completed_tests’:

```
data = {'Project_ID': ['Project 1',  'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1', 'Project 1'], 
     'participant_id': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1005, 1104, 1104, 1104, 1104], 
     'day':['Day_1', 'Day_2', 'Day_3', 'Day_1', 'Day_1', 'Day_2', 'Day_3', 'Day_4'], 
     'no_completed_tests': [5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5],
     'completed_tests_(per_participant)': [12, 12, 12, 3, 14, 14, 14, 14]}
```

To achieve what I want I’ve done the following:

```
Data['completed_tests_(per_participant)'] = np.nan
pd.pivot_table(Data, index=[ 'participant_id'], values=['no_completed_tests'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

All I have displayed in the `completed_tests_(per_participant)` is NaN

I have also tried (without satisfactory result):

```
Data ['completed_tests_(per_participant)']= Data.groupby(['participant_id']).sum()
Data ['completed_tests_(per_participant)']= Data.groupby(['participant_id']). ['no_completed_tests'].agg('sum')
Data = Data.groupby(['participant_id'])['no_completed_tests'].agg('sum')
```

Any ideas/ suggestions how can I achieve my goal?
I am still learning how to program and trying to apply knowledge from data science course so I am probably doing really silly mistakes (I am a biologist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to pivot here. You can groupby and transform:

```
df['completed_tests_(per_participant)'] = df.groupby('participant_id')['no_completed_tests'].transform('sum')

# display the column:
>>> df[['completed_tests_(per_participant)']]
   completed_tests_(per_participant)
0                                 12
1                                 12
2                                 12
3                                  3
4                                 14
5                                 14
6                                 14
7                                 14
```